# facebook - Get article likes, shares and comments without FQL

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-opengraph

Is it possible to get like-, share- and comment counts for an article (or other open graph object) without using FQL?

I'm aware that API v2.1 introduced the URL node which includes two fields called 'share_count' and 'comment_count'. But these are not the same values as the ones you get through FQL.

- 'share_count' appears to be the sum of likes, comments and shares.
- 'comment_count' appears to be a different value entirely, possibly comments published through the Comments Box plugin.

For a comparison, see the following links. (I'm unable to make the FQL query in Graph API Explorer for some reason.)

- [Old](http://www.sharedcount.com/#url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com)
- [New](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=%3Fid%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%26fields%3Dshare&version=v2.4)

Since API v2.0 will eventually expire, I'd rather not develop apps based on this version. But right now, I don't see any way of getting like-, comment- and share metrics for articles. I'd like to retrieve these metrics because they are more detailed than the new 'share_count' value.

Any ideas?

Comment: At present using link_stat FQL on v2.0 is the only option to get the drill down that you are looking for 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat/
SELECT like_count, comment_count, share_count,total_count FROM link_stat WHERE url = 'http://www.google.com'.

That breakdown isn't available via url or engagement
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/url
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/engagement

Comment: I believe you're right sir. Put that in an answer below so I can approve it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At present using link_stat FQL on v2.0 is the only option to get the drill down that you are looking for

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat

```
SELECT like_count, comment_count, share_count,total_count FROM link_stat WHERE url = 'google.com'; 

"data": [
{
  "like_count": 3385562,
  "comment_count": 2034401,
  "share_count": 7514540,
  "total_count": 12934503
}]
```

That breakdown isn't available via url or engagement https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/url https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/engagement

Maybe by the time FQL is deprecated there may be further endpoints that can give you the data.